# If $p$ and $q$ are primes of the form $4k+3$, and $x^2 \equiv p \pmod q$ has no solutions, show $x^2 \equiv q \pmod p$ has two incongruent solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Prove or disprove:

> If $p$ and $q$ are primes of the form $4k+3$, and  $x^2 \equiv p \pmod q$ has no solutions, show $x^2  \equiv q \pmod p$ has two incongruent solutions

I think it is a true statement $(p,q)=1$ and $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $q\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Since $x^2 \equiv p \pmod q$ has no solution then $(p/q)=-1$ and since $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $q\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ then $(q/p)=1$

Hence, $x^2$ ≡ q (mod p) has two incongruent solutions.

is this right?

Comment: Law of quadratic reciprocity. If $a$ is a solution to $x^2\equiv q\pmod p$, so is $-a$.

Comment: It is confusing that you write $(p,q) = 1.$ Better $p \neq q$  After that, you are alright, it is quadratic reciprocity

Answer (score 0):

We wish to show that

> If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes of the form $4k+3$, and if $x^2 \equiv p \pmod q$ has no solutions then $x^2 \equiv q \pmod p$ has two incongruent solutions.

Your proof looks good! Here's how I would improve the formatting.

If $x^2 \equiv p \pmod q$ has no solutions, then
$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right) = -1$$
(This is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)).

Now by [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity),

$$\left(\frac{q}{p}\right) = 1$$

which means that there exist an integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv q \pmod p$. Clearly, $-x$ is also a solution so we have two incongruent solutions.

Comment: Of course they're odd primes because both are $\equiv 3\pmod 4$

Comment: One more note, you said "If $x^2\equiv p\pmod q$ then $(p/q)=-1$" but you probably meant to say the congruence $ x^2\equiv p\pmod q$ has no solution. Right?